# Wordpress: Post same blog entry to multiple pages

Tags: plugins, wordpress

On my Wordpress site, I have the main blog entry page, then I have two sub blog pages.  I would like to know if there is a way so that whenever authors submit a post to the main page, that same post is also posted in one of the sub blog pages.  I would think that there is a plugin to do this sort of thing.  The closest I have come to is this plugin, http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicate-post/ but it does not seem that this one automates the process.

I may just edit that plugin to do it automatically, but I would like to at least try and see if there is one already out there.  Ideally, I would like the plugin to have a selection of which page the blog should be added to on the edit page.  Something like `Add this post to Blog Page 1 or Blog Page 2` with check boxes by either page.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have 2 sub blog pages in which you want to have the option to display any posts taht are submited by authors. I'm thinking at a custom post meta that you can use to filter posts in the sub blog pages this way if the author wants to place the post in blog page 1 it will set the postmeta to blog1 if he wants it in blog page 2 it will set the postmeta to blog2, all you'll have to do then is to filter the posts to include postmeta blog1 in blog page 1 and blog2 in blog page 2.

something like:

```
$args = array('meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'blogPage',
        'value' => 'blog1',
        'compare' => '=',
        'type' => 'text'
    )) // for blog page 1
```

and

```
    $args = array('meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'blogPage',
        'value' => 'blog2',
        'compare' => '=',
        'type' => 'text'
    )) // for blog page 2
```